# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar de forma aleatoria un array de objetos que ya está ordenado?

Tags: javascript

tengo un array por ejemplo este

`javascript`

```
[
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 1",
        "score": 10
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 2",
        "score": 10
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 3",
        "score": 10
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 4",
        "score": 10
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 19",
        "score": 8
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 43",
        "score": 6
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 87",
        "score": 3
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 99",
        "score": 1
    }
]
```

El cual estoy ordenando por score, utilizando lodash
de esta manera:

```
_.orderBy(data, ['score'], ['desc'])
```

Como pueden notar `nombre 1`, `nombre 2`, `nombre 3` y `nombre 4` tienen el mismo score, pero al ordenarlo, `nombre 1` siempre queda mas arriba que `nombre 2`, `3` y `4`, mi idea es ordenarlos por score, pero que los que tengan el mismo score no siempre queden en el mismo lugar

por ejemplo

```
[
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 2",
        "score": 10
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 3",
        "score": 10
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 1",
        "score": 10
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 4",
        "score": 10
    }
]
```

o

```
[
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 3",
        "score": 10
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 1",
        "score": 10
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 4",
        "score": 10
    },
    {
        "nombre": "nombre 2",
        "score": 10
    }
]
```

No se si me estoy explicando bien, pero alguien sabe como puedo lograr esto ?
Mis saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cual es el objetivo final de obtenerlos desordenados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias por tan buena pregunta, he encontrado una forma concreta aunque no genérica, es la siguiente:

```
function randomScoreOrder(a, b) {
  if (a.score === b.score) {
    const random = Math.random() * 10;
    if (random >= 5) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  } else if (a.score > b.score) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.score < b.score) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

const newOrderedlist = list.sort(randomScoreOrder);
```

Esta función te devuelve ordenados de mayor score a menor los items y en los que tienen el mismo valor, uno aleatoriamente.

P.D. Se podría mejorar pasándole el nombre del campo por el que quieres ordenar

Comment: Buenisima, muchisimas gracias, me funciona perfecto